# Jquery tooltip that stays open on hover

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm working with the following tooltip:  http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

This works really well, but is there any support for implementing a tooltip that stays open on hover? Or a way to implement that?

Comment: You want it to stay open permanently? Or just while you hover another particular element?

Comment: Ideally, it should stay open while I hover over the element that triggered the tooltip OR over the tooltip itself. Anywhere else, it can close.

Comment: It would be a help if we could see the HTML you're working with. And the jQuery with which you're calling the plug-in.

Comment: Sorry for my answer, i thought you meant open all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I opted to create a seperate jquery plugin for a 'sticky' tooltip.

Its basically the same as the usual tooltip, except it doesn't hide itself on mouseout.

If you want to see the implementation, check the 'createHelper' method in the original jquery tooltip and modify it as follows:

```
helper.parent = $('<div id="' + settings.id + '"><h3></h3><div class="body"></div><div class="url"></div></div>')
            .bind('mouseleave', function () { hide(undefined, settings); })
            // add to document
            .appendTo(document.body)           
        // hide it at first
            .hide();
```

The above basically does: create a div parent, and keep it open until the user leaves the open tooltip.