# Angular UI Tooltip overflowing screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have  a tooltip (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) with  a status notification, but when this notifications is to large, it overflows the screen limits. here is a print of what is happening:

[image]

I couldn't find any attribute in angular ui that deals with this problem.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make a Plunker? I just tried and my long tooltip automagically word wrapped to multiline and fit fine on the screen.

Comment: Proof this issue is still relevant: Angular-ui's own demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3CrirzusD5ONSdIjnX4A click the `"Or use custom triggers, like focus:"` box.  If the screen is small enough, this tooltip hangs off the right. Angular ui's bootstrap does not have position:auto. The tooltips have a max-width, but they are not being prevented from hanging off the page.  Fix is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution does not use Angular-UI, just Angular and Bootstrap. Bootstrap is not necessarily required, just simplifies the process a bit:
http://plnkr.co/edit/jLThSTrLUapAG8OLW44m?p=preview

Before I go any further, an alternative to this example would be to add a CSS class with [word-wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) and [white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) properties to your tooltip class. Using Chrome or Firefox's developer tool, inspect the elements until you locate the classes responsible for setting the tooltip ui; then add these properties to them in your style.css custom CSS document.

Now, for this particular solution, we create a tooltip directive and allow it to take a placement attribute to determine positioning

Angular code, where we destroy the tooltip after we are done to prevent a memory leak:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

angular.module('test').directive('tooltip', function () {
           return {
              restrict: 'A',
              link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                 $(element)
                         .attr('title', attrs.tooltip)
                         .tooltip({placement: attrs.placement});
                 scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    element.tooltip('destroy');
                 });
              }
           }
        })
```

CSS Code, where we have to override some of the Bootstrap defaults:

```
.tooltip-inner {
   width: auto;
   min-width: 180px;
   background-color: #c0d3d2;
   color: #000000;
   font-weight: 600;
   margin: 0 5px 0 -5px;
   /*margin-left: -5px;*/
}

/* Make tooltips opaque */
.tooltip.in { opacity: 1.8; filter: alpha(opacity=100); }
/*Change tooltip arrow color for bottom placement*/
.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow {
   top: 0;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -5px;
   border-bottom-color: #c0d3d2;
   border-width: 0 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the popover is inheriting some positioning information from the container it's in. Try setting `popover-append-to-body` so that it's not in that container any longer.

There is a bug in the current release of Angular UI, so you actually have to set:

```
popover-append-to-body="true"
```

But, that will be fixed on the next release so you don't need the ="true" part, just set the attribute.

Comment: This worked for me by adding ```tooltip-append-to-body="true"```.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a couple of things to get my popover to "work" using **[uib-popover-template](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#popover)**

1. Add the `popover-append-to-body="true"` attribute.

   - This appends popover to `$body` instead of the parent element
2. Add the `popover-placement="auto top"` attribute.

   - It will try to display top, otherwise attempts a more user-friendly placement.
   - I tried with `auto top-left` but it seems to squish very large amounts of text.
3. Wrapped content in a `<div style="max-height: 300px; overflow: auto;">`

   - This put a boundary on the container and will add scrolling only when necessary.